# Spring boot+Spring Batch+MySql not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am creating a spring batch application using spring boot and **mysql** as the JPA repository and deploying on cloud foundry. While duing **cf-push** the batch process is crashed with error Process crashed with type **web**. 
However the underlying error message shows

> 2019-01-11T07:56:08.856-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT]
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to
>   commit new sequence value changes for BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ
>   2019-01-11T07:56:08.856-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:177)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>   2019-01-11T07:56:08.856-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
>   2019-01-11T07:56:08.856-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:154)
>   ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.0.RELEASE]
>   2019-01-11T07:56:08.856-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:151)
>   ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.0.RELEASE]

I have been facing this issue for last 3 days and tried lot of sugggestions from google but no luck yet. 
The error shows

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an autowired JobLauncher and @Bean JobLauncher which made two calls to DB at the same time(atleast I am thinking this as the reason :) ). When I removed the @Bean JobLauncher as I am using Spring boot, the application started working fine.