# Spring batch Could not obtain last_insert_id(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch, hikaricp

I have build a spring boot application which will use spring batch with myql database. My application what it does is when customer send request It will start new batch job with mysql data & saved processed data in same mysql database. So far all the functionality working fine. But when I run the load test It will throw this error & I couldn't find the roor cause. Seems like this is spring batch related issue.
This is the error

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain last_insert_id(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: HikariPool-1 - Interrupted during connection acquisition
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(MySQLMaxValueIncrementer.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:154) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:150) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) [spring-tx-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:181) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137) [
```

This will trigger when start the batch job

```
jobLauncher.run(job, getJobParameters(paramaters));
```

And these are the spring batch configurations

```
    @Bean(name = "myJobLauncher")
    public JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

     @Bean
    public TaskExecutor myTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(concurrentJobs);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(PoolSize);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(queueLimit);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

These are the executor pool configurations.
concurrentJobs =50,poolSize =30, queueLimit = 50. And I have used the default hikari connection pool configurations. Is there anyone who have faced this issue with spring batch jobs ?

Comment: None of these two [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643616/spring-batch-mysql-sequence-could-not-obtain-last-insert-id-reguarding-engin) & [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54148367/spring-bootspring-batchmysql-not-working) helps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch MySql Sequence "Could not obtain last\_insert\_id()" reguarding engine type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643616/spring-batch-mysql-sequence-could-not-obtain-last-insert-id-reguarding-engin)